# Add number in a column values in table for all records

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have table named "product". It has a column 'delivery_price' with some values. I want to add 100 in all the fields.

Something like this:

```
   delivery_price = 100 + delivery_price
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In your `rails console` you could do :

```
Product.all.each do {|p| p.update_attribute(:delivery_price, p.delivery_price + 100) }
```

or as follows to avoid seeing all the SQL output

```
Product.all.each do {|p| p.update_attribute(:delivery_price, p.delivery_price + 100) }.count
```

This will load all your Product records and add 100 to delivery_price.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this SQL query:

```
UPDATE TABLE products SET delivery_price = delivery_price + 100;
```

Open your RDBMS console/UI Manager/Whatever, connect to the database and pump this little query up.

Comment: I am using mysql. Sorry but new to this. Not getting where to run the query u suggested.

Comment: You better read something about databases first then. This kind of stuff, connecting, modifying, tweaking you database is essencial for web development. Start here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql.html

Comment: Or download any gui client that can connect to a database and give you a visual of what you are doing. Like SquirrelSQL here: http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/